# How do I find quantile of vector which contain values and their occurrences in c++?

Tags: c++, vector, quantile

I have a vector which elements are pairs with value and its count of occurrences (values are unique). I want to find vector quantile as if values were repeated count of occurrences times. What is the best way to do it with respect to run-time complexity?

**E.g.** if vector consist of 3 elements (1,4), (2,5), (3,1), then 0.1-quantile is 1 and 0.5-quantile is 2, because the whole vector is 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3.

nth_element will do it if I create vector with repeated elements but I don't want to since it requires a lot of memory.

I have the same questions for map instead of vector since I can replace the latter with the former.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Observe that the Qth quantile, Q in [0,1], is the element Q fraction of the way through all the elements of the fully-expanded vector (or map--this makes no difference).

In O(n) time you can sum the counts, e.g. 10 in your example.  Then multiply this by Q to get the target index, so for Q=0.5 you have target=5.

Now in O(n) time you can scan the elements of the compact vector again, summing the counts until you reach the target index (5).  In your example this would happen at (2, 5).  The first value here is the answer.

Comment: If vector wasn't sorted, it will be O(n * log n), won't it?

Comment: @ForestGoose: Yes, if the vector isn't sorted by element, you'd need to sort it first in O(n log n).  Of course if it's a map it will be sorted by default.

Answer (score 0):

using partial_sum and lower_bound can find quantiles in logaritmic order:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <utility>
#include <numeric>
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> v {{1,4}, {2,5}, {3,1}};
    std::map<int,int> cum;
    std::swap(v.begin()->first, v.begin()->second);
    std::partial_sum(v.begin(), v.end(), std::inserter(cum, cum.begin()), 
        [](const std::pair<int,int>& a, const std::pair<int,int>& b)
        {
            return std::make_pair(a.first + b.second, b.first);
        }
    );
    std::swap(v.begin()->first, v.begin()->second);
    auto quantile = 0.1;
    std::cout << cum.lower_bound(quantile * cum.rbegin()->first)->second << std::endl;
    quantile = 0.5;
    std::cout << cum.lower_bound(quantile * cum.rbegin()->first)->second << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Wait, why logarithmic? partial_sum is linear in the distance between v.begin() and v.end()

Comment: @ForestGoose partial_sum used to build the map so later efficiently be searched. search is done using lower_bound that it's complexity is logaritmic